Flutter - no internet detection across all routes
I'm trying to detect internet connection loss on all routes and managed to do that by adding a builder in the MaterialApp and it works fine but the problem is that after internet connection is regained, the route that is loaded is sometimes wrong(e.g: loades entry route instead of onboarding although there is nothing in the sharedPrefs).
 return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      builder: (_, child) => InternetConnectionWrapper(child: child!), // used for displaying no internet screen all across the app
      title: 'X',
      theme: darkTheme(context)
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
      routes: routes,
      initialRoute:
          /* no data ? -> login if web, else onBoarding; data available? user -> map screen, workshop-> dashboard screen */
          userData.isNotEmpty ? userData[userType_index] == "user" ? entryPointRoute : dashboardLauncherScreenRoute :  kIsWeb? loginScreenRoute: onboardingScreenRoute,
    );

How could this be implemented accordingly? Thank you!
Detect internet connection loss and after reestablishing, reload the same route that was active when internet connection loss was detected.

From my point of view I would do the following.

Add in the connectivity_plus package to dependencies.

Create a service to listen to connectivity changes:




import 'dart:async';
import 'package:connectivity_plus/connectivity_plus.dart';

class ConnectivityService {
  final _connectivity = Connectivity();
  StreamController<ConnectivityResult> connectionStatusController = StreamController<ConnectivityResult>();

  ConnectivityService() {
    _connectivity.onConnectivityChanged.listen((ConnectivityResult result) {
      connectionStatusController.add(result);
    });
  }
}




Create a Custom Route Observer:



import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomRouteObserver extends RouteObserver<PageRoute<dynamic>> {
  String? currentRoute;

  @override
  void didPush(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic>? previousRoute) {
    if (route is PageRoute) {
      currentRoute = route.settings.name;
    }
    super.didPush(route, previousRoute);
  }
}




Finally use the CustomRouteObserver and manage navigation based on connectivity:



import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  final routeObserver = CustomRouteObserver();
  final connectivityService = ConnectivityService();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    connectivityService.connectionStatusController.stream.listen((status) {
      if (status == ConnectivityResult.none) {
        navigatorKey.currentState?.pushNamed('/noInternet');
      } else {
        if (routeObserver.currentRoute != null) {
          navigatorKey.currentState?.pushNamed(routeObserver.currentRoute!);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'X',
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => HomeScreen(),
        '/noInternet': (context) => NoInternetScreen(),
        // define other routes
      },
      navigatorObservers: [routeObserver],
    );
  }
}



PS: Make sure you handle the initial route correctly depending on user data and platform. The CustomRouteObserver keeps track of navigation, and when the connection status changes, it redirects accordingly.
Hope this helps.

Hello, Thanks or providing a solution. Unfortunately, the stream doesn't listen when I go to another activity :( . so doesn't work across the whole app

Hey again, so the problem is now that after putting the app in background, or killing it and restarting again, the stream isn't listening and also that the callback for listening is called 2 or more times, so route is pushed multiple times.

Managed to get it working. Many thanks

Hey My bad just got up did you anything that mad it work?

yes, I'm not returning to the same route, I'm returning to a predefined routed based on sharedPreferences, so it will not lead to any issue.
